# Creating a new Virtual Environment for PyPy3 in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv, pypy

When I try to create a new virtual environment using pypy3 as the base interpreter I get this error in PyCharm:

I'm using a MacOS sierra on a 64-bit MacBook pro late-2015 with PyCharm 2016.3

Executed Command:

```
/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/packaging_tool.py list
```

Command Output:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpypy-c.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/3228991/.virtualenvs/pypy3_venv/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Maybe make sure ``/Users/3228991/.virtualenvs/pypy3_venv/bin/libpypy-c.dylib`` exists?  If needed, as a symlink to the real ``libpypy-c.dylib``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpypy-c.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/3228991/.virtualenvs/pypy3_venv/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
```

Means that your program is using a dynamic library called libpypy-c.dylib, although you linked your dynamic library to your program during compiling. But you have to tell your program where is the dylib in run-time in Pycharm.

Set up dynamic library environment variables for your project:

1.Run/Edit Configurations

2.Click Python, below the "Before Launch" click the "+" button

3.Put DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to Name box

4.Put the path where your libpypy-c.dylib file is in Program box

Comment: actually now it's saying can't execute binary file?

Comment: have you had a chance to run it from directly interpreter?

Comment: yes,the base interpreter works fine. it when i try to create a virtualenv that it breaks